# Creating VB . NET quiz template

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am learning VB at the moment and i'm planning how i'm going to make a simple quiz style web application. I want to have a series of questions, one per panel, that a user can select from multiple choice and proceed to next question with at least one option needing to be selected before going to the next question. At the end users get their score out of X.

Forgetting the validation and other bits i need. My thinking is to use a series of panels that have my questions in, so one panel per question, and by default they are all set no invisible bar the first question. Then as the user selects the question the next panel is revealed and the previous hidden, and so on etc.

Is this a bad way to approach the problem? I'm not sure if it's perhaps too clunky or if i am right in looking it in this way. I would just like some suggestions so i can get on the right footing.

Thanks in advance as always.

Comment: The downside to your approach is that you'll bake in all the data your application needs into the EXE and have a hard time changing the questions/answers.  You'd always have to compile and manipulate the vb forms designer every time you wanted to add / remove something.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider creating a XML file with the questions / answers.  Make one panel and load the first question into the label that holds the question element and populate the radio buttons with the sub elements of the XML for that question.

Question.Xml content:

> ```
> <Question text="2+2">
> <Answer text="1"/>
> <Answer text="3"/>
> <Answer text="4"/>
> <Answer text="2"/>
> </Question>
> ```

Then use the following code to populate the question/answer, modify as needed.

```
Sub LoadQuestion()
    Dim xmlReader As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
    xmlReader.LoadXml("Questions.xml")
    Dim question As System.Xml.XmlNode = xmlReader.FirstChild()
    lblQuestion.Text = question.Attributes("Text").Value.ToString()
    For Each answer As System.Xml.XmlElement In question.ChildNodes
        'do something to add each answer...
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi William thanks, is this just easier to manage over my method? I did try your suggestion but i got an error for the Xml.XmlDocument 'Is not defined'

Comment: Which visual studio version are you using, check help->about.

Comment: I missed your note about it being a Web Application.  The example I gave was based on a windows forms application.  I'll adjust it.

Comment: Adjusted it, when you get red underlines in code try putting your text cursor on any of the characters and pressing CTRL+[PEROID].  It will give suggestions to fix the problem automatically.  This is what I did once I put the code into a web project.

Comment: If System.Xml.XmlDocument doesn't fix your problem, right click on your project in the Solution Explorer, select Add Reference, and under the .Net Tab locate System.Xml (and add it).

Comment: The Adjusted code didnt throw up any erros now but my label is not populating the data, i might be doing something wrong.